# Is this logical relation correct?

Tags: boolean, logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

Is this logical relation valid?

```
(X or Y) and (XX and YY) = (X and XX and YY) or (Y and XX and YY)
```

Intuitively, the equivalance seems right but it doesn't work on my code. I don't know whether the equation is wrong in the first place or my code is buggy.

Comment: Quick question, is `XX` in any way related to `X`? Or is it just another name for a parameter? As in, is it possible to just re-write that to `(A or B) and (C and D)`

Comment: @VLAX it's just another name. Thank you for the answer. I think there's some bug in my code, since the logic is right.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to verify I'm not misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two equations are equivalent. When unpacking the brackets with the OR you do indeed have to AND `X` with `(XX and YY)` as well as `Y` with `(XX and YY)` again and OR the two. So the result is `(X and XX and YY) or (Y and XX and YY)`

If that's not convincing enough, then we can generate the truth table for each. Interactive using the snippet functionality:

```js
const table = document.querySelector("table");

function one(X, Y, XX, YY) {
  return (X || Y) && (XX && YY);
}

function two(X, Y, XX, YY) {
  return (X && XX && YY) || (Y && XX && YY);
}

function test(X, Y, XX, YY) {
  const addContent = addTo(table);
  addContent(X);
  addContent(Y);
  addContent(XX);
  addContent(YY);
  
  addContent(one(X, Y, XX, YY));
  addContent(two(X, Y, XX, YY));
}

const addTo = table => {
  const row = table.insertRow();
  return content =>  row.insertCell().textContent = content;
}

//generate all permutations of 4 booleans and test them with each boolean equation 
for(let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  const X = Boolean(i & 8);
  const Y = Boolean(i & 4);
  const XX = Boolean(i & 2);
  const YY = Boolean(i & 1);

  test(X, Y, XX, YY);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr > td:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: right;
}

td {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>Y</th>
      <th>XX</th>
      <th>YY</th>
      <th>(X or Y) <br/>and <br/>(XX and YY)</th>
      <th>(X and XX and YY) <br/>or <br/>(Y and XX and YY)</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, the results are the same for each.